# In Windows 10, how to automate a set of actions? i.e. turn the Internet off, wait 2 sec, turn on again

Tags: windows-10, macros, autohotkey, user-interface, tasks

My Internet randomly disconnects and I have to go to Adapter options to turn it off and back on again in order for it to start working again. It's tedious and I wish I could just press a key combo to do this task. I tried googling it but all I get is advice on macros for specific software e.g. Excel or Outlook, not Windows itself. There's also AutoHotkey but not sure if that's what I need.

Comment: Don't you use any router / are you directly connected to the internet? If you're using a router, it's not the internet which disconnects, but your local network. Nevertheless, you can try the PowerShell command `Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Restart-NetAdapter` (in an elevated console). If it works and you don't want to find the root cause, you can create a shortcut to the powershell script (e.g. C:\ProgramData\netRestart.ps1) on your Desktop and assign it a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Q: Is this a wifi adapter?  If so, it should automatically reconnect, without any manual intervention.  Q: Do you know  *where* the problem is occurring?  In your PC's adapter?  At your wifi router?  Your Internet provider (e.g. cabling to your home/office, intermittant satellite service, etc)? 
 Do you know *what* is causing the disconnect?

Comment: @paulsm4 Unfortunately I don't know the root cause, and there are some complicating issues (such as me using a VPN to bypass my ISP blocking traffic and some other stuff) and the problem comes up seldom enough for me to not want to spend time digging for the cause, but rather wanting to automate the simple workaround.

Comment: @swbbl that almost perfectly answers it! The .ps1 file doesn't run in Powershell by default, (even right click > run in powershell doesn't work), but I added a path to it in a separate shortcut invoking Powershell, and then it works. The only minor nitpick is I have to run it as Admin every time - wish I could just double click the file - but it's still a lot better. So, I would accept this comment as the answer if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1 via PowerShell

You can create the following PowerShell Script which also prompts UAC if the current user is not elevated (has the admin token).
You should create it somewhere, where only admins have write access (for security reasons), like `C:\ProgramData\` or `C:\Windows\` and remove write permissions for normal users after saving.

The relevant code for a network restart in the script is `Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Restart-NetAdapter`.

```powershell
using namespace System.Security.Principal
$ErrorActionPreference = 'STOP'

try {
    if ([WindowsPrincipal]::new(([WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
        Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Restart-NetAdapter
    } else {
        # restart powershell as admin
        $pwshExePath  = (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path
        $argumentList = '-File "' + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + '" ' + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
        Start-Process -FilePath $pwshExePath -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $argumentList
    }
} catch {
    Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ -ErrorAction Continue
    Read-Host 'Press [Enter] to close'
}
```

Then create the following shortcut on your Desktop.
**Target:** `powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\ProgramData\RunAs.ps1`
*OR for PowerShell Core:*
**Target:** `pwsh.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\ProgramData\RunAs.ps1`

Adding `powershell.exe` / `pwsh.exe` (with some parameters) will allow you to run the shortcut (of the script) directly by double click.

You can also add a keyboard shortcut as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

## Option 2 via Batch

You can use a batch file as well, like the batch file provided as answer by @harrymc and then also create a shortcut as in `Option 1`

Using a shortcut will allow you to run it as admin if you set it in the properties (Hint: This is not allowed for PowerShell (.ps1) files):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `.bat` file with the following commands :

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface "Connection name" disabled
timeout /t 2
netsh interface set interface "Connection name" enabled
```

These commands do not require elevation.

You could create a desktop icon that points to the `.bat` file and
optionally give it a hotkey.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, it doesn't work without Admin rights. Connection doesn't change. With admin, it works. But thanks for this alternate suggestion as well.

Comment: Strange - you don't need admin for disabling the adapter via the GUI.

Comment: I made some research into this, and apparently the ability to permit a standard user to disable/enable network adapters still exists as historical remnant in the Group Policy Editor, named "Ability to enable/disable a LAN connection", but doesn't work beyond Windows XP. No idea why Microsoft decided to abolish it, but apparently it no longer exists.

Comment: @harrymc Want to add something, that may be relevant for your last research. Keyword: "Integrity Level". Read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/mandatory-integrity-control